# php how to create file from browser

Tags: php, centos7, fopen

When a user clicks submit I am trying to create a file.

Centos 7

php 7.2

I have tried to modify the code a couple different ways also tried file_put_contents does not seem to work.

Code:
index.php

```
<form action="sendmail.php" method="post">
<input type="text" placeholder="fname" name="fname">
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

sendmail.php:

```
<?php
$fname = $_POST["fname"];
echo "bef: " . $fname;
$myfile = fopen("/signupemails/" . $fname . ".txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo "aft: " . $fname;
$txt = $fname;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Directory to create file

```
[root@webserver webdir]# ll -d /signupemails/
drwxrwxrwx. 2 apache apache 51 Aug 25 20:41 /signupemails/
```

If i change sendmail.php and hardcode the $fname and run php sendmail.php it will create the file fine

Creating it from the browser I get "Unable to open file!"

Comment: What is the value of `$fname` when `fopen` fails?

Comment: @melpomene I have edited the code and I get the following output: bef: NAMEUnable to open file! I do not think aft is getting call because the script is dying on the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work as is, i just tested it and it seemed to work fine.

Is selinux disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```php
$myfile = fopen("/signupemails/" . $fname . ".txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

PHP doesn't have the same [logical "or" semantics](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) as JavaScript. That expression returns a boolean, so `$myfile` will equal `true` instead of the file handle.

Write it this way:

```php
$myfile = fopen("/signupemails/" . $fname . ".txt", "w");
if (!$myfile) die("Unable to open file!");
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest do with js 
For example

```
function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

// Start file download.
download("hello.txt","This is the content of my file :)");
```